# Adding Data in SQL Database using excel file data with the help of Xlookup like function

Tags: excel, sql-insert, vlookup

I am new at SQL, but for simplicity of some of my work I need to know
I have a data in SQL which is null in some cases as there is no data in DATABASE yet, in the software we insert the data from EXCEL using Copy paste,
I want to add data directly in the database using data of EXCEL with insert function but it should act like Vlookup
Ex. - In SQL if the first column's first cell is "A"  and the second column's cell is null, then the value of the second cell is in excel I want that data to be inserted in SQL so that it can update in the main database.
The software for which I need to insert data is WMS on which we can't run MACRO as it is restricted.

Comment: I can't work out your criteria for inserting data - you need to supply some examples. But regardless, if you can't run macros, then I suggest you use formulas to concatenate values and create a SQL  Insert statement on each line. Then you can copy paste those into a client too land run them. I assume you have some kind of SQL client tool on your "WMS"?

Comment: Without macro you can't add data from excel to SQL. You can import excel from SQL server directly.

Comment: You can use VBScript, Powershell, Python, whatever to import excel into SQL, but if macro's are disabled, I'm sure all of those other methods are also disabled